# How to make PDF viewer responsive to changes in Debian

Tags: debian, text-processing, latex, inotify, evince

I have a fresh Debian 8.1 installation and am trying to make its usability feel like OSX.

I run

```
xelatex document.tex && evince document.pdf &
```

but it only successfully runs `xelatex` and does not update the PDF document in the viewer which is already open.

How can I make evince fetch the updated document from the disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evince is updating the pdf automatically. No need to restart it. At least mine does on Debian 8.1.

When it's not reloading automatically anymore, maybe you ran out of inotify watches. Increase it with:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p
```

Mine is set to 65536 by `/etc/sysctl.d/30-tracker.conf`.

Comment: Mine does not. This is strange. I have Lenovo G50-30 which is built from cheap hardware so probably some firmware problems. How do you run `xelatex` to get updated pdf?

Comment: I am pretty sure, that it's neither a firmware nor a xelatex problem, as Evince uses inotify.

Comment: What is your default max_user_watches?

Comment: `fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 65536`

Comment: How did you fetch it?

Comment: `sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches` as root.

Comment: This answer works also after restart. Thank you for your answer!